# How to delete unnecessary files from the repository

Tags: git, version-control, command, gitignore

I have a repository (Git) with the code, I made a few commands push.
But I forgot to do .gitignore file and now I'm in the repository files with the extension .pyc.

Is removing them manually give any effect?
Is there any command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1.**
Add the files that you wish to ignore to the .gitignore

For example: `./*.pyc`

**Step 2**
As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/1901744):

```
git rm -r --cached
```

The update would be visible the next time you push.

Comment: Thank you. Is this command: "git rm -r --cached" delete all files with the extension pyc?

Comment: This just deletes whatever files git has cached but are no longer tracked. You can have those files on your local system as long as you have a `.gitignore` that mentions the files that need not be tracked.